# Default implementation of a class in Gson

Tags: gson

I am using the Gson library to make Json objects.  I made a serializer for my Class.  From what I see I have to use the builder and do .registerTypeAdapter on it whenever I want to use my serializer.

Is there a way around this?  Is there a way to have the serializer I wrote implicitly associated with my class?  If not what do people usually do to keep their code clean when using their own serializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way around this? Is there a way to have the serializer I wrote implicitly associated with my class?

Not with Gson.

> If not what do people usually do to keep their code clean when using their own serializers?

Use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org).  With Jackson, there are [multiple ways to register serializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).

Comment: My ultimate answer was to make my own factory to make my Gson that puts all my serializers on it.  While I didn't decide to use Jackson, this was a decent answer, and the only answer, so I accepted it.